# What happens to Jupiter's moons at the end of "2010: The Year We Make Contact"?

Tags: 2010-odyssey-two

I know that Jupiter becomes a second sun and that Europa develops a complex biosphere, but what happens to all the other 60+ moons?  David Bowman's "All these worlds are yours except Europa" message mentions the other moons in abstract, but the movie only shows Europa's changes in the millennia following Jupiter's conversion to a star.  In what ways do the other moons change?

Comment: Their evolution is going to be pushed along by the monoliths

Comment: The presumption is that, over time, humanity will colonize the other Jovian moons.

Comment: I removed part of your original post to narrow the focus to one question. *Both* questions are good, though, so I'd encourage you to post the removed part as a separate question.

Comment: It’s possible the closest ones, like Metis and Adrastea were destroyed along with *Discovery* during the star ignition process.

Answer (score 2):

Of the four major moons, Europa was the only one with an abundance of liquid water (under the ice). So, the monolith was warning humanity to keep clear of Europa and allow this life to develop.

The message also states "ALL THESE WORLDS ARE YOURS" before the proscription against interfering with Europa - meaning humanity is free to expand and inhabit the other Jovian moons.

Clarke, the author of 2001 and 2010, also wrote a third and fourth novel - 2061 and 3001 - which show that man did expand as invited, as well as disobey the Europa injunction. They're not bad reads, though possibly a little dated in some of the social and science aspects, and explain a bit more about the monoliths' purpose.

Comment: "in singe of"??

Comment: @Randal'Thor - autocorrect... haven't had my Sunday morning coffee yet

Comment: I figured it was autocorrect, just couldn't work out what for :-)

Comment: I always thought “all these worlds” meant the whole solar system.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I suppose it's open to interpretation, but the ignition of Jupiter/Lucifer directly benefits the Jovian moons most significantly, so I always thought the "all these worlds" was limited to them.